# NullReferenceException when using GetAsync to call web service

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await, asp.net-web-api2

I want to call an async Web Service method from inside an async method and user a WPF Window in order to ask the user for the username and Password.

The Code Looks similar to this:

```
private async Task GetUsers()
{
        List<User> users = new List<User>();

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var authenticationWindow = new AuthenticateWindow();
            authenticationWindow.ShowDialog();

             //... Code to get the token ...
            var token = "myToken";

            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:56057/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", token);

            var response = await client.GetAsync("api/users/");

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                users = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<User>>();
            }
            else if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
            {
                throw new UnauthorizedAccessException();
            }
        }

        foreach(var user in users)
        {
        }
}
```

If I execute this Code I get the following exception:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
```

This happens when calling client.GetAsync("api/users/"). It has probably something to do with context switching happenening because I opened the window.

How can I solve this Problem?

The call stack just Shows "External Code".

If I remove the following two lines everything works fine:

```
var authenticationWindow = new AuthenticateWindow();
authenticationWindow.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: await client.GetAsync("api/users/").ConfigureAwait(true) ?

Comment: Could you include stack trace and inner exceptions if those are present?

Comment: On what line does the NRE happen?

Comment: It happens at  var response = await client.GetAsync("api/users/");

Comment: If it happens on that line then either `client` is null (likely) or there's a weird bug in HttpClient (unlikely). Can you [edit] your question with the stack trace?

Comment: I get the same errror when using await client.GetAsync("api/users/").ConfigureAwait(true).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a UI element being instantiated and used within the scope of a service, try to instead separate these two from each-other. It sounds like you need to have this logic of requesting users in the `AuthenticateWindow`, perhaps on its `Loaded` event:

```
// Safe UI entry point for async work, i.e.; event handler.
async void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var users = await GetUsersAsync();
    // Take action on the user's from the API.
}
```

And then have the `GetUsers` (renamed more appropriately to `GetUsersAsync`) focus only on consuming the `HttpClient` and corresponding API, materializing and returning the `List<User>` like so:

```
async Task<List<User>> GetUsersAsync()
{
    List<User> users = new List<User>();

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
         //... Code to get the token ...
        var token = "myToken";

        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:56057/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", token);

        var response = await client.GetAsync("api/users/");

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            users = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<User>>();
        }
        else if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
        {
            throw new UnauthorizedAccessException();
        }
    }
    return users;
}
```